# how to get total of TimeSpan properties inside a Sum() methode in c#?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, timespan

I'm working on a Asp.Net Core project right now. I have an entity named `Course` and an entity named `Episode`. they have one-to-many relation so that each `Course` has many `Episods` inside itself.

This is my Episode.cs:

```
public  class Episode
    {
        [Key]
        public int EpisodeId { get; set; }


        [Required]
        public int CourseId { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "عنوان اپیزود")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="لطفا {0} را وارد کنید")]
        [MaxLength(ErrorMessage ="{0} نمیتواند بیش تر از {1}کاراکتر باشد")]
        public string EpisodeTitle { get; set; }


        public string EpisodeFileName { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "مدت زمان اپیزود")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "لطفا {0} را وارد کنید")]


        public TimeSpan? EpisodeTimeLength { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "رایگان")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "لطفا {0} را وارد کنید")]
        public bool IsFree { get; set; }




        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;



        #region Navigation Properties

        [ForeignKey("CourseId")]
        public Course.Courses.Course Course { get; set; }
        
        #endregion
  }
```

My question is about this part: `public TimeSpan? EpisodeTimeLength { get; set; }`.

I want to use the method **OrderBy()** to sort my courses so that which course has more total **EpisodeTimeLength** become at first.

For example, if the total **EpisodeTimeLength** of my first `Course` be 12h, and the second one be 15h, the second one will be considerd at first.

I tried the below ways:

```
1- dbContext.Courses.OrderBy( c => new TimeSpan( c.Episodes.Sum(e=> e.EpisodeTimeLength.Ticks));
2- dbContext.Courses.OrderBy( c =>( c.Episodes.Sum(e=> e.EpisodeTimeLength));
```

But none of them worked and I got the error: **cannot implicity convert type 'System.TimeSpan' to 'long'**!

So anyone can tell me How I can handle it?

Comment: Have you tried `c => c.Episodes.Sum(e => e.EpisodeTimeLength.Ticks)`?

Comment: Yse I have, but it says " dos not contain a difinition for 'Ticks' "

Comment: @juharr comment seems right.
Just add null check since I see in your class EpisodeTimeLength is nullable, so:

`c => c.Episodes.Sum(e => e.EpisodeTimeLength?.Ticks ?? 0)`

Comment: You may have to do the ordering on the client side.  Try putting an `AsEnumerable` before the `OrderBy`.  That of course will not be a great idea if you are then doing something like `First` or `Take`.

Comment: @YomB There is a version of `Sum` that handles `long` and it would be better to use `TotalSeconds` as `Seconds` is the number of seconds with whole minutes, hours, and days truncated off.  Ultimately the issue has more to do with translating the code to SQL.

Comment: Oh yeah that's right, I guess it was in earlier versions of .NET that Sum (and other LINQ methods) were accepting ints but not longs

Comment: @Yom B Didn't work

Comment: @Hossein what's the error?

Comment: @YomB `the number of ticks  contained in this instance`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your TimeSpan variable is nullable, so you need to use Value in your expression and you do not need create TimeSpan object inside LINQ method. This code should work:

```
dbContext.Courses.OrderBy( c => c.Episodes.Sum(e=> e.EpisodeTimeLength.Value.Ticks));
```

Comment: But another question, what should I do if i wanted to assign                                                 `c => c.Episodes.Sum(e=> e.EpisodeTimeLength.Value.Ticks) ` to a variable(for ewxample: **TimeSpan myVar**)?

Comment: You could pass number of ticks into TimeSpan constructor: var myVar = new TimeSpan(NumberOfTicks)

Answer (score 1):

Since `TimeSpan` already defines an `operator +`, you can use it. Try this:

```
.OrderBy(c => c.Episodes.Select(e => e.EpisodeTimeLength.Value)
  .Aggregate(TimeSpan.Zero, (x, y) => x + y))
```

This first projects all episodes onto the `Value` of their lengths (assuming that you want a bad exception if an episode length has no value), then aggregates with the built in `+` operator.

If you do not want an exception, but want to use a zero length when no length is known, then this:

```
.OrderBy(c => c.Episodes.Select(e => e.EpisodeTimeLength ?? TimeSpan.Zero)
  .Aggregate(TimeSpan.Zero, (x, y) => x + y))
```

If you are absolutely sure there will always be at least one episode in each course `c`, then you can omit the `TimeSpan.Zero` from the `Aggregate` call (the second line). So that would be

```
.OrderBy(c => c.Episodes.Select(e => e.EpisodeTimeLength.Value)
  .Aggregate((x, y) => x + y))
```

respectively

```
.OrderBy(c => c.Episodes.Select(e => e.EpisodeTimeLength ?? TimeSpan.Zero)
  .Aggregate((x, y) => x + y))
```

Finally, you could want the logic that if at least one episode is missing a length, then the total should be undefined (`null`). In that case use the lifted `+` which exists automatically on `Nullable<>`. That would be:

```
.OrderBy(c => c.Episodes.Select(e => e.EpisodeTimeLength)
  .Aggregate((TimeSpan?)TimeSpan.Zero, (x, y) => x + y))
```

or:

```
.OrderBy(c => c.Episodes.Select(e => e.EpisodeTimeLength)
  .Aggregate((x, y) => x + y))
```

if you know `.Episodes` is not empty, and in these cases you would get all the courses with "undefined" total length sorted by themselves before the shortest courses.

---

Of course the `.Select` are not strictly needed since they could be built into the lambda used by the `.Aggregate`, for example:

```
.OrderBy(c => c.Episodes
  .Aggregate((TimeSpan?)TimeSpan.Zero, (x, y) => x.EpisodeTimeLength + y.EpisodeTimeLength))
```

Well, since `.OrderBy` is all you ask for, you might as well just use `.Ticks` as suggested by fatherOfWine's good little answer. However, I see in your comment to his answer that you may want to keep the total course lengths. In that case, you can just say `.Select` instead of `.OrderBy`, for example:

```
var allCourseLengths = dbContext.Courses
  .Select(c => c.Episodes.Select(e => e.EpisodeTimeLength.Value)
  .Aggregate(TimeSpan.Zero, (x, y) => x + y));
```

and so on.